# Black screen on locking the elementary OS with windows + L key

Tags: display, lock

I installed Elementary OS a couple of days back. The windows + L key worked fine till sometime back but when i now do the same the screen turns black and i have no other option but to force shutdown it

It works fine in locking the screen from the UI

I checked other solutions online but was unable to find the answer. Can anyone suggest how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes my screen turns black.  When I press windows + L again it comes back to the start screen and prompts me for login password (if enabled) and then resumes where you left off